# .htaccess not working in centos web panel

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, centos

mod_rewrite is enabled

vhosts.conf set to allow

```
<Directory "/home/chinatow/public_html">
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

.htaccess (should be ok)

```
#--- Uncomment this line for production or testing server
#SetEnv CI_ENV production

#--- Allow remote API access; change "*" to "your-domain.com" for better security
#--- Note: require Headers mod enabled (sudo a2enmod headers)
#Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

#--- URL rewrite
#--- Note: require Headers mod enabled (sudo a2enmod rewrite)
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

i suppose everything works well, but end up .htaccess not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can used this **.htaccess** file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

turn out it was the htaccess error. my url is

xx.xx.xx.xx/~account

the htaccess should be

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~account/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```